# What Currency will the Messiah introduce in the Messianic Age?

Tags: messiah, money, olam-haba-world-to-come

Does anyone know what the currency will the Messiah introduce in the Messianic era?

Is there such a thing as "the original Torah currency"? And does anyone mention switching to this currency?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you planning on buying it up to make a good profit ;)

Comment: This question needs some clarification! Why do you think currency will change, and what prompted your question?

Comment: see Brachot 34b where shmuel states that nothing will change when the Messiah comes (that is no permanent changes in the course of nature מנהגו של עולם). see also Rambam end of Melachim Umilchamot.

Comment: It was a dream that I had that prompted the question. I envisioned a world that didn't evolve around fiat currency, and things/assets (i.e. possessions) that we have today were not valued based on currency manipulation by our central banks but on mutual understanding, wisdom, respect, and so on - which are spiritual in nature, as opposed to being materialistic. Of course, this is all based on a dream I had, and should be taken with a grain of salt. I apologize if this answer is an unsatisfactory one..was just curious what others thought on the subject.

Comment: @Anonymous The answer is not unsatisfying as it clarifies exactly why you asked the question. Consider editing that information into the question.

Comment: It looks that the main reason for closing the question is the complete lack of sources. According to Rambam's ruling (MU"M) we don't deal with the Messianic times as we have no grasp of it, and we'll live and see what's coming. Another problem is that the Messianic times span different epochs from the coming of the Messiah in our "reality" to building of the temple and revival of the deads which is not in the reality we know.

Comment: However, my conclusion is that the any currency will become obsolete at the end, as **money is a tool to reach spiritual perfectness through physical interactions** and in the days when we (and the whole world) will reach that all tools (incl Mitzvot) will become obsolete.

Comment: I think the question is clear - as we return to the "original Torah" what's the "original Jewish currency"? Did Moses coin his own currency in the wilderness? Are we going to mint it back?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/87692/evidence-for-pre-greek-jewish-currency "evidence-for-pre-greek-jewish-currency"</a>