# Evidence for pre-Greek Jewish currency?

Tags: history, money

The Torah is full with money statements - such as acquisitions, donations, fines and payments, presenting different names and values for money - such as Shekel, Sela, Kesef, Ksitah and more. But the Torah was given on Mt Sinay and spoke "the language of the people". If I understand right, the only "money" Jews had at that time was Egyptian.

The Talmud is full with discussions about currencies and money (see Kiddushin 11, B"M and more). Many of those currencies practiced in Greece and Babylon, but the Talmud makes bold statements about the ancient (pre second-temple era) generations, up to Moses, using the same currencies, including statements of Abraham, Yacov, Yehoshua issuing coins (B"K 97).

I've checked numerous sources, but all of them assign implementation of coins as currency (as opposite of weight) to at earliest 8th century BCE, which is approximately in the middle of the first temple period. Therefore, no currency in ancient Egypt, no currency in the desert, no currency during Moses, Yehoshua, Zkenim, even Kings David and Salomon didn't have it.

How do we reconcile those facts?

Comment: The silver *shekel* is mentioned by Abraham and Ephron. The *kesitah* is mentioned in connection to Jacob (and Job).  Deuteronomy mentions currency (וצרת כסף). You don't have to look to the Talmud for statements that assign currency to even the earliest periods. What evidence are you looking for?

Comment: Up to that point where there were actual coins issued, precious metals were measured by weight, the shekel, beqa, pim, etc. This is evidenced by such early references(Genesis 24:22, etc) as the weight of the presents given to Rebecca, the nose ring weighing half a shekel(a beqa), and the bracelets weighing 10 shekels.  Plenty of inscribed stone weights have been found with their weights scratched into them. The sela was the name of a later coin, the tetradrachma equivalent, minted during Bar-Kochba's time.  It was equal to four drachmas/denarii, which were the smaller silver coins circulating.

Comment: @ba those could be weights not currencies (equivalent to saying he bought the cave for 400 oz of silver)

Comment: Torah usually uses the verb "to weight" (לשקול) in conjunction with כסף, as in "וישקול אברהם לעפרון את הכסף אשר דיבר באוזני בני חת ארבע מאות שקל כסף עובר לסוחר", so Abraham **weighted** 400 Shekel, **not counted**.

Comment: @ba the point being made is that standard weights of metal that normally were used as we use currency today. Over lasochir meant that were accepted by everyone in trade without difficulty. That is, with no suspicion of adulteration.

Comment: my point is - what evidence do we have, that Jews used currencies in times of the Torah and not only weights, as it contradicts the existing findings?

Comment: I don't see any clear evidence from Torah sources in your question for the claim that you seek substantiation for in non-Torah sources. If you claim (IMO correctly) that "shekel of silver" in the Torah means weight rather than coins, then you should quote your Torah sources and show how you know they mean coins rather than weight.

Comment: @ba the important thing is there were no stamped coins whose exchangability was tied to their stamp. It was just raw weight of metal. The earliest minted coins are from turkey around the time of Hezekiah. It wasn't the modern sense of coins as currency before then.

Comment: @msh210 That is in the quote from Bava Kama attributing issuing coins to Abraham, Jacob and Joshua